# URL(String: ) がnilを返す

Tags: swift, ios

iOSでファイルをサーバーからダウンロードするためのコードを書いたのですが、以下の箇所で
`url` が `nil` になってしまいます。

```swift
let url: URL = URL(string: encodeUrlString)!
```

`encodeUrlString`の値をデバッガで確認すると、

```
encodeUrlString String "https://stg-reception.ai-force.ai/asset/dummy-file/Md4efrxZn4bPbYf4.mp4"
```

となっており、特に問題はなさそうなのですが・・・。
どなたか分かる方おりませんでしょうか。

```swift
let urlString: String = movieDataStore.remoteFileUrl! + movieDataStore.remoteFileName!
let encodeUrlString: String = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
let url: URL = URL(string: encodeUrlString)!
let request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

Alamofire.download //（以下、省略）
```

Comment: 「urlがnilになって」いることはどのように確認されましたか? `print`文などで確認されましたか? 現在のXcodeにはバグがあり、デバッグエリアの変数表示は一部のデータ型を正しく表示できません。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。デバッガでの確認しかしておりませんでした。
試しに

print("url = " + url.absoluteString)

と入れてみたところ、
url = https://stg-reception.ai-force.ai/asset/dummy-file/Md4efrxZn4bPbYf4.mp4
と正常に出力されました。

ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現在のXcodeにはバグがあり、デバッグエリアの変数表示は一部のデータ型を正しく表示できません。
print文で確認すると、ちゃんと表示されます。

Comment: 可能であれば具体的なバージョンも明記してあると、より役立つ情報になるかと思います。("現在の" という表現だと将来バージョンアップした時に意味を成さなくなります)